# Reg Ex for even number of 0s and 1s

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that determines if a string (of any length) matches a regex pattern such that the number of 0s in the string is even, and the number of 1s in the string is even. Can anyone help me determine a regex statement that I could try and use to check the string for this pattern?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: is there any limit as to how long that string (containing the binary) might be? how many bits?

Comment: There is no limit (except for whatever the string character limit is obviously). :-(

Comment: @BartKiers Sorry i missed your initial post. I have tried breaking the options down to repeatable 2,4,8 character sections but have failed to find something that is capable of capturing all available options.

Comment: Why do you need to use regex? It would be simpler to 
a) Replace all ones with blanks/zero length strings
b) Get length of string/number- > "L"
c) Check if L is even.

Comment: @pst, does the pumping lemma work? You just take `p = 4`, and `y` to be the first occurrence of `11` or `00` (or if that doesn't occur in the first 4 characters: `1010` or `0101`), then it satisfies the condition of the pumping lemma (as far as I understand), and the proof by contradiction fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I have come up with a solution to the problem:

```
(11+00+(10+01)(11+00)\*(10+01))\*
```

Comment: +1. Clever solution. It would be written as `^(11|00|(10|01)(11|00)*(10|01))*$` in common regex flavors. The trick here is to realize that the question is in fact equivalent to "even number of `A`s in a string of `A`s and `B`s", where `A` is matched by `10|01` and `B` is matched by `11|00`.

Answer (score 8):

**So completely reformulated my answer to reflect all the changes:**

This regex would match all strings with only zeros and ones and only equal amounts of those

```
^(?=1*(?:01*01*)*$)(?=0*(?:10*10*)*$).*$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30m98)

I am working here with [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The big advantage here of a lookahead assertion is, that it checks the complete string, but without matching it, so both lookaheads start to check the string from the start, but for different assertions.

1. `(?=1*(?:01*01*)*$)` does check for an equal amount of 0 (including 0)
2. `(?=0*(?:10*10*)*$)` does check for an equal amount of 1 (including 0)
3. `.*` does then actually match the string

Those lookaheads checks:

```
(?=
    1*    # match 0 or more 1
    (?:   # open a non capturing group
        0     # match one 0
        1*    # match 0 or more 1
        0     # match one 0
        1*    # match 0 or more 1
    )
    *     # repeat this pattern at least once
    $     # till the end of the string
)
```

Comment: It works; though it doesn't recognize `11`, or `1111`, but it works... Well done! ;-)

Comment: So I'm just a tad bit confused. That's pretty incredible. But how does that not accept the pattern 00000? Because we've matched 0 with each of your 3 separate [0^\s]* checks and additionally a 0 with each 0 check.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon added workaround to allow the completely absence of a digit.

Comment: @canton I updated my solution. That was because it expected at least 2 of each digits. Each of those assertions has to be full filled.

Comment: Can't you just change the `+` in the look-ahead to `*` to avoid using the `|` and still accept `11` etc?

Comment: @dbaupp no then the lookahead would test for the empty string, but not for a not occurrence of that digit.

Comment: Doesn't the `$` stop it just matching the empty string (unless the string is empty)?

Comment: @dbaupp Each assertion has to be true, if in `(?=(?:[^0\s]*0[^0\s]*0[^0\s]*)*$)` the outer `*` is zero you effectively have `(?=$)` that means the assertion is true when after the start of the string (because of the `^` at the start) follows `$`, so its true when the string is empty.

Comment: @stema, Yes, I understand that. Can't you allow the lookaheads to match the empty string, and just restrict it to non-empty using the non-lookahead section. i.e. change `+` to `*` in the look-aheads (avoiding the `|`) and change the (non-lookahead) `[01]*` to `[01]+`. (Also, it's not even clear that the empty string should fail: `""` contains 0 `1`s and 0 `0`s, and 0 is even.)

Comment: @dbaupp I thought again over my solution and of course there is a solution without alternation. I updated my answer.

Comment: If you're only going to allow `0` and `1` anyway (via the part of the regex that actually consumes the matching characters, namely the `^[01]*$` part, then you don't need all those `[^0\s]*` and `[^1\s]*` - `1*` and `0*` will work just as well.

Answer (score 3):

For even sets of 0s, you can use the following regex to ensure that the number of 0s is even.

```
^(1*01*01*)*$
```

However, I believe that the question is to have both an even number of 0s and also an even number of 1s. Since it is possible to construct a non-deterministic finite automaton (NFA) for this problem, the solution is regular and can be represented using a regex expression. The NFA is represented via the machine below, S1 is the start/exit state.

```
S1 ---1----->S2
|^ <--1----- |^
||           ||
00           00
||           ||
v|           v|
S3----1----->S4
  <---1------
```

From there, there's a way to convert NFAs to regex expressions but it's been a while since my computation course. There's some notes below that seem to be helpful in explaining the steps required to convert a NFA to a regex.

http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/sp09/cs373/lectures/lect_08.pdf

Comment: Based on this, I think `^((1|0(11)*10)(00|0110)*(1|01(11)*0)|0(11)*0)*$` works. (It can possibly be factorised smaller). http://regexr.com?30m8j

Comment: I've been working on the solution as well but that looks right to me. I'm not sure what the tradeoffs are between using the lookaheads. However, I'm guessing this is a homework problem (otherwise there are far easier ways of tackling this solution).

Comment: Nope, I was wrong. That one doesn't match `10111101`, but this does: `^((1|0(11)*10)(0(11)*0)*(1|01(11)*0)|0(11)*0)*$`

Answer (score 2):

#### RE-UPDATED

---

**Try this :** *[ check out this demo : http://regexr.com?30m7c ]*

```
^(00|11|0011|0110|1100|1001)+$
```

<del>**Hint :**</del>

<del>Even numbers are divisible by 2, thus - in binary - they always end in zero (`0`)</del>

Comment: This is for even binary numbers ... does not mean that count(0) is even and count(1) is even ...

Comment: @pst Looks like you've got a point here; I misread the question... Let me think about it a bit...

Comment: Yes, @pst is correct. I'm not looking at the binary value; I'm only concerned with the numbers of 1s and 0s. Thank you.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon wouldn't that allow the string 0111? that would only assert that the total number of characters is even, I believe.

Comment: @canton I just re-re-updated. Check out. Baaah! I'm close; I can feel it! :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Now, how about for strings of length 6? 8? 10? 12? The issue is that each new length of 2 introduces a *new* pattern not build-able from the previous.

Comment: I have considered something of that nature, but I believe I'm then missing the string 11101110. and I think it grows exponentially worse because I would need to even allow for the option of 1 concatenated with any even number of repeated 0s and 1 at the end (i.e. "10000000000001" or "10000001")

Comment: @canton it's true. we're still missing those; aaaaargh, give me a sec. Quite a problem this one, huh?! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not a regular expression (which is likely to be impossible, although I can't prove it: the proof by contradiction via the pumping lemma fails), but the "correct" solution is avoiding a complicated and inefficient regular expression all together and using something like (in Python):

```
def even01(string):
     return string.count("1") % 2 == 0 and string.count("0") % 2 == 0
```

Or if the string has to consist only of `1`s and `0`s:

```
import re
def even01(string):
     return not re.search("[^01]",string) and \
            string.count("1") % 2 == 0 and string.count("0") % 2 == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(0((1(00)*1)*0|1(11|00)*01)|1((0(11)*0)*1|0(11|00)*10))*$
```

If I haven't overlooked anything, this matches any bit string where the number of 0s is even and the number of 1s is even, using only rudimentary regex operators (`*`, `^`, `$`). It's slightly easier to see how it works if written like this:

```
^(0((1(00)*1)*0
   |1(11|00)*01)
 |1((0(11)*0)*1
   |0(11|00)*10))*$
```

The following test code should illustrate the correctness - we compare the result of the pattern match against a function that tells us if a string has an even number of 0s and 1s. All bit strings of length 16 are tested.

```
import re

balanced = lambda s: s.count('0') % 2 == 0 and s.count('1') % 2 == 0

pat = re.compile('^(0((1(00)*1)*0|1(11|00)*01)|1((0(11)*0)*1|0(11|00)*10))*$')

size = 16
num = 2**size
for i in xrange(num):
    binstr = bin(i)[2:].zfill(size)
    b, m = balanced(binstr), bool(pat.match(binstr))
    if b != m:
        print "balanced('%s') = %d, pat.match('%s') = %d" % (binstr, b, binstr, m)
        break
    elif i != 0 and i % (num / 10) == 0:
        # Python 2's `/` operator performs integer division
        print "%d percent done..." % (100 * i / num + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to solve *within* the same sentence (starting with ^ and ending with $), you are in deep trouble. :-)

You can make sure that you have an even number of 0s (with `^(1*01*01*)*$`, as stated by @david-z) **OR** you can make sure that you have an even number of 1s:

```
^(1*01*01*)*$|^(0*10*10*)*$
```

It works for strings with small lengths as well, such as "00" or "101", both valid strings.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been working on lookaheads and lookbacks in my spare time, and using lookahead the problem can be solved while taking also account for the single 1s and/or the single 0s. So, the expression should also work for 11,1111,111111,... and also for 00,0000,000000,....

```
^(((?=(?:1*01*01*)*$)(?=(?:0*10*10*)*$).*)|([1]{2})*|([0]{2})*)$
```

Works for all cases. 
So, if the string consists of only 1s or only 0s:

```
([1]{2})*|([0]{2})*
```

If it contains a mix of 0s and 1s, the positive lookahead will take care of that.

```
((?=(?:1*01*01*)*$)(?=(?:0*10*10*)*$).*
```

Combining both of them, it takes into account all string with even number of 0s and 1s.